# solrj returns the same result for different queries

Tags: solr, solrj

Here is my code:-

```
    SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://arlmsendeavour01:8983/solr/ImageMatch").build();

    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setRequestHandler("/select");
    //System.currentTimeMillis();
    String q = "{!cache=false}*:*&debugQuery=true&sort=lirefunc(eh,\"opKg0dKEtZOSsaSBkfPChsTEopGykqHExYTEw5GylbKx8KKXkqHRww==\")+asc";
    query.setQuery("q");

    QueryResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = client.query(query);
    } catch (SolrServerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
        System.out.println(results.get(i)/*.getFieldValue("id")*/);
    }
```

I am using a function query lirefunc where the first parameter defines whether it is a color or edge or texture and the second parameter is the extracted feature from the image. Every time i run the code that is even for different images and different features I get the same output as if it is extracted from the solr xml. The out put remains the same for all the types of queries. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `query.setQuery("q");` - did you mean `query.setQuery(q);` (no quotes qround **q**)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query.setQuery("q");` - this sets the query to the string `"q"`. I'm certain that's not what you meant to do.

The `setQuery` method isn't used to set a query string either - it's used to set whatever is present in the `q` parameter (the query) to Solr.

There are [separate methods for each part of the request to Solr in SolrJ](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_1_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrQuery.html).

To set the `sort=` parameter, use [addSort](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_1_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrQuery.html#addSort-org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery.SortClause-):

`query.addSort(SortClause.desc("lirefunc(eh,\"opKg0dKEtZOSsaSBkfPChsTEopGykqHExYTEw5GylbKx8KKXkqHRww==\")"));`

Comment: It worked once.. But the next time the output was picked from the solr cache. What shall i use to set the cache to false? Posting my updated code snippet here.                                                                              
String q = "{!cache=false}*:*";
query.setQuery("q");
      query.addSort(SortClause.asc("lirefunc(cl,\"FQYiEB4aDxYQDxAODBAPEBQQDxAQEAoYDxMSEBA0EAUIDw4=\")"));

Comment: You're still setting the query to `"q"`. You probably want `query.setQuery(q)`.